# How do I add informations about bugfixes or security fixes to rpm spec files?

Tags: centos, rpm-spec, dnf

I build rpms with my own spec files. Now I want to add information about bugfixes or security fixes, so that dnf can understand them like:

`# dnf check-update --bugfix`

or

`# dnf check-update --security`

How can I make this work?

Thx, Joerg